# Remote EJB calling: No EJB receiver available for handling

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, ejb

I was trying to connect remote EJB using this [tutorial](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/EJB+invocations+from+a+remote+server+instance), but all that have got is `No EJB receiver available for handling`. This is how I connect:

```
    public static boolean CreateContext() throws ServletException {
        System.out.println("Well-well");
        boolean successCreate = false;
        final Hashtable props = new Hashtable();
        // setup the ejb: namespace URL factory
        props.put(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, "org.jboss.ejb.client.naming");
        props.put("jboss.naming.client.ejb.context", true);
        // create the InitialContext
        Context context = null;
        try {
            context = new javax.naming.InitialContext(props);
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        IssapageHome ref = null;


        try {
            ref =
(IssapageHome)context.lookup("ejb:" + "/ejb667//TheIssapage!" +
                             IssapageHome.class.getName());


        } catch (NamingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            context.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            //initContext = new javax.naming.InitialContext(env);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log("Exception creating InitialContext: " + e.toString());
        }

        try {
            // String JNDIName = "ejb/issapage";
            // Object objref = initContext.lookup(JNDIName);
            // initContext.close();
            myIsapageHome =
                    (IssapageHome)PortableRemoteObject.narrow(ref, IssapageHome.class);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log(" Issapage bean home not found: " + e.toString());
        }
        try {
            myIsapageRemote = myIsapageHome.create();
            successCreate = true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            log(" Could not create the Issapage bean: " + e.toString());
        }
        return successCreate;
    }
```

I catch exception after this statement:

```
myIsapageRemote = myIsapageHome.create();
```

Full st:

```
11:44:44,054 ERROR [stderr] (http-/127.0.0.1:8080-1) java.lang.IllegalStateException: EJBCLIENT000025: No EJB receiver a
vailable for handling [appName:, moduleName:ejb667, distinctName:] combination for invocation context org.jboss.ejb.clie
nt.EJBClientInvocationContext@103ad01b
11:44:44,058 ERROR [stderr] (http-/127.0.0.1:8080-1)    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientContext.requireEJBReceiver(EJBC
lientContext.java:735)
11:44:44,062 ERROR [stderr] (http-/127.0.0.1:8080-1)    at org.jboss.ejb.client.ReceiverInterceptor.handleInvocation(Rec
eiverInterceptor.java:116)
11:44:44,067 ERROR [stderr] (http-/127.0.0.1:8080-1)    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.sendRequest(E
JBClientInvocationContext.java:183)
11:44:44,071 ERROR [stderr] (http-/127.0.0.1:8080-1)    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.sendRequestWithPoss
ibleRetries(EJBInvocationHandler.java:253)
11:44:44,075 ERROR [stderr] (http-/127.0.0.1:8080-1)    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.doInvoke(EJBInvocat
ionHandler.java:198)
11:44:44,080 ERROR [stderr] (http-/127.0.0.1:8080-1)    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.doInvoke(EJBInvocat
ionHandler.java:181)
11:44:44,084 ERROR [stderr] (http-/127.0.0.1:8080-1)    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBInvocatio
nHandler.java:144)
11:44:44,088 ERROR [stderr] (http-/127.0.0.1:8080-1)    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy10.create(Unknown Source)
```